# Jquery : get Height and Width of an uploaded image with Uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am using C# .net (razor, mvc3) and the Jquery Plugin Uploadify, but I have a problem to get the height and the width from my uploaded image.

Here the part where I want them : (I use Uploadify and onComplete to show the image)

```
'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response) {
    if (response == "OK") {
        $("#DivImg").addClass("loading");
        var htmlString = "<img id='Image' src=\"../../uploads/" + fileObj.name + "\" alt=\"" + fileObj.name + "\"  />";
        $("#DivImg").html(htmlString);

        //I would like to get height just here but $("#Image").height give me 0
```

Comment: Hmm na warranty but try this $("#image").attr('offsetHeight');

Comment: What does $('#DivImg').css('height') return?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
The first give me undefined.
The second give me the height of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using :

```
$("#Image").height
```

try using:

```
$("#Image")[0].height
```

but be aware that the image needs to load first, before you can actually get its height attribute.

Comment: I try it, but it gives me 0.
The problem is that the image is not loaded, i used : 
.load(function() and alert inside and the result is good, but I can't use it inside a dynamical function :(

Answer (score 1):

You are using "height" as a variable, but it is actually a function, you should try *"jQuery("#Image").height();"* to get the height of the dynamic image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment, you could get the height by calling

```
ParseInt($('#DivImg').css('height'), 10)
```

Comment: I didn't try your new code. But i solved the problem by myself :)
In fact, it was just a loading image problem :
`$("#Image").load(function () {
                        var img = this;`


It's very strange, if I use my function with $("#Image").height it doesn't work
But with img.height it's ok.